# How to add textbox value to datagrid cell using query c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I'm creating a windows form that will allow my group at work to check in & out computers from our spare cabinet. I have two tables, an 'Assets' table & Inventory Log table. The user will fill out the GUI and select the asset they want from the check out screen. The problem I am having is trying to pass the foreign key 'InventoryID' to the log table. I have the main textbox's bound to datagrid cells but I am unable to do this with the inventory ID because I have it bound to a textbox so the user does not have to enter it every time.

I have tried creating an insert query that takes the textbox and converts it to int and then inserts it into the method but it catches an exception. Note, this query works when I test it in the query builder. I have also tried adding it with the binding source property but it cant find the index.

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get asset number 
        string asset = txtAssetNumber.Text;
        //get invID from textbox
        int InventoryID = Convert.ToInt32(txtinv.Text);
        //this query changes available status to 'No'              
        inventoryTableAdapter.SetNo(asset);    
        //runs query to determine what rows have 'Yes'
        inventoryTableAdapter.Available(this.loanerCabDataSet.Inventory);

        try
        {        
            //add new row to log table
            inventoryLogBindingSource.AddNew();
            //suppose to insert the ID into table
            inventoryLogTableAdapter.insertinvid(InventoryID);

            //set textbox back to today's date
            txtOutDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            this.Validate();
            this.inventoryBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.loanerCabDataSet);

            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Query:

INSERT INTO InventoryLog (InventoryID)
VALUES        (?)

Comment: Change your `catch` part in order to show the exception and share it with us, it might be helpful

Comment: The exception states "You must enter a value in the 'InventoryLog.InventoryID" field." When I put a breakpoint on the query it shows the InventoryID value, but for some reason it is not being passed into the field. I have it set up as an int in my database and converting it to int for the query

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a way around it.

Created insert query and instead of binding all of the textboxes to the column, I created variables and passed them into the function.

Heres what it looks like now.

inventoryLogTableAdapter.Insert(InventoryID, customer, tech, loaneddate, datein, location, ticket, notes);